# Verify the test for json output in postman for arraylist

Tags: arrays, json, testing, postman

Have a json output without any message. How do I verify my test for user-specific values only? As I want my test to verify for users, firstname, roles and how many offices

```
{
    "Status": "OK",
    "Message": "",
    "users": [
        {
            "address": {
                "city": "test",
                "state": "CL",
                "zip": "60585"
            },
            "mobile": "",
            "userId": "789455061",
            "email": "test@abc.com",
            "enabled": true,
            "fax": "",
            "firstName": "fortest",
            "id": "6ec-asd-132",
            "lastName": "test",
            "licensedStates": [],
            "connectid": "123456",
            "organizations": [
                {
                    "OrgID": "110465",
                    "offices": [
                        {
                            "OrgID": "11465",
                            "address": {
                                "city": "newcity",
                                "state": "BL",
                                "zip": "60585"
                            },
                            "id": "",
                            "name": "Test Data Pvt LTd"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "789434",
                    "name": "Test Data Pvt Ltd"
                }
            ],
            "phone": "",
            "roles": {
                "Tester": true,
                "Dev": false,
                "Manager": false
            },
            "suffix": "",
            "title": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

declaring response json as variable. then tried, then need for roles too.

```
pm.test("testfordata",responsejson.users[0].enabled.is.equal(true);
```

> error: cannot read property 'equal' of 'undefined'

Comment: Post the actual code, not a screenshot of it please.

Comment: hope code helps ? i am looking for user and roles list test pls share inputs

Comment: Not in the comments when it's not formatted. Just edit the question and add this inside a code block.

Comment: editing done pls share inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very targeted test based only on the data set above and doesn't account for checking more than the first object in the `users` array:

```
pm.test("testfordata", function () {
    let jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.users[0].enabled).to.be.true
    pm.expect(jsonData.users[0].firstName).to.equal("fortest")
    pm.expect(jsonData.users[0].roles).to.have.keys(["Tester", "Dev", "Manager"])
    pm.expect(jsonData.users[0].organizations[0].offices.length).to.equal(1)
});
```